# Entity Framework, Code First, Layered application

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 projects WinformApp, LogicProject, DataAccess. Where should I add entity framework NuGet package and what should be in App.config in every project? I want to have a connection to MSSQLserver on the same computer.

Simplified project:
https://github.com/McThrok/StackOverflowQuestion

Answer (score 0):

You should reference Entity Framework in only your Data Access Layer, as it is data access specific. This means if you wish to change technology later down the road and not use EF anymore, your changes are restricted to only this layer and the rest of your code performs exactly the same.

Comment: OK so I have to work on interfaces not to access directly anything from EF. But with or without EF in Logic i cant connect SQLserver.

System.InvalidOperationException: 'No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.'

Comment: @McThrok: The **code** involving EF should only exist in the DataAccess project. However, due to how config files work, the application (i.e. your Winforms project) will need to contain the necessary **config settings**. If you use EF via Nuget, it automatically creates a config file (in the DataAccess project). Simply open the file, copy the config settings, and add them to your Winforms config file (do not copy them over existing settings of course!)

Comment: @McThrok: Note that if you e.g. build a small console application that works directly with the Logic project, that console application will also need the necessary config details in its config file. The principle is the same here, a config file comes from the top level project, so all settings must be registered there.